# Get content sent from the server using phps file_get_contents when the returned status is 400

Tags: php

I am using phps `file_get_contents` to connect with my API server. It works well when the server returns with 200 status (it return the content from the api server). The problem is when the api server returns with 400 status. If the api server returns with 400 status the function simply returns FALSE (not the content).
here is what I get from **$http_response_header**

```
[ "HTTP\/1.1 400 Bad Request", 
"Server: nginx\/1.16.1", 
"Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 05:39:09 GMT", 
"Content-Type: application\/json", 
"Content-Length: 117", 
"Connection: close", 
"Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", 
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", 
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection" ]
```

Now my question is how can I get the **content** sent fron the API server when the status is 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enable the [ignore_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors) flag:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'ignore_errors' => true,
    ],
]);
var_dump(file_get_contents('http://example.com/', false, $context));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rather use curl than `file_get_contents` as this one has better support for error handling:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{url}"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

// handle any other code than 200
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
    // your handling code
    print_r($output);
}

curl_close($ch);
```